# How to get next row with id

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have a table like this;

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Doe |
| 5 | Rose |
| 11 | Michael |
| 15 | Pedro |

and my select query like this;

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 5 | Rose |

I want to select next rows according to my query which like this;

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Doe |
| 11 | Michael |

`1 John`s next row is `2 Doe` and `5 Roes`'s next row `11 Michael`

Comment: What have you tried? What query did you execute to get just `John` and `Rose`?

Comment: Not sure I understand - are you running these queries back to back? Or do you want the result to include all four rows? Description is very confusing and I don't understand how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One of many ways to do this:

```
WITH 
    RowNumbers AS (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber
        FROM
            TableName -- replace with your table name
        )

SELECT
    Id,
    Name
FROM
    RowNumbers
WHERE
    RowNumber IN (
        SELECT 
            RowNumber+1 
        FROM 
            RowNumbers 
        WHERE 
            Name IN ('John', 'Rose')
        )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE to create row_numbers and then select and join to it.

```
create table my_data (
  id integer, 
  name varchar(20)
  );

insert into my_data (id, name) values 
(1, 'john'), 
(2, 'doe'), 
(5, 'rose'), 
(11, 'michael'), 
(15, 'pedro');
```

```
with row_data as (
 select id, name, 
  row_number() over (order by id) as rn
 from my_data
  )
select b.id, b.name
  from row_data a
  join row_data b 
    on a.rn + 1 = b.rn
 where a.name in ('john','rose')
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | doe |
| 11 | michael |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/g5OKAvMH)